# how to print all columns and rows of an SQL view from Python using pyodbc and pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pyodbc

I am able to connect to my data in SSMS from VScode using Python. I can print 1 column in the terminal but I can not print all of the columns. The column that I am able to print, only prints if I use that column name in my select statement as opposed to *. I have tried using multiple columns in select, that also did not work.

Error Message:

```
raise ValueError(f"Shape of passed values is {passed}, indices imply {implied}")
```

ValueError: Shape of passed values is (128, 1), indices imply (128, 14)

Ultimately I am attempting to take all of the data (columns and rows) from an SQL view and push it into an excel file.

Thanks

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd


cnxn = pyodbc.connect(r'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=serverName;DATABASE=myData;Trusted_Connection=yes;')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
script = """
SELECT * FROM [dbName].[schema].[vewName}
"""
cursor.execute(script)
columns = [desc[0] for desc in cursor.description]

data = cursor.fetchall()

df = pd.DataFrame((data), columns=columns)

print(df)


#writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r'C:\Users\nnolting\py.xlsx')
#df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='bar')

#writer.save()
```

Comment: [pd.read_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html)

Comment: pandas can do this directly.  `df = pd.read_sql( script, cnxn )`.

Comment: Thank you @TimRoberts - this worked. I am now working on getting this df to excel.

Comment: Well, pandas can ALSO do that, with `df.to_excel`.  That might not be sufficiently customizable, but it's a start.